# WSO2 Enterprise Integrater 6.6.0 Response transform XML to Json using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt, transformation, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I got a response from endpoint in WSO2 enterprise Integrator as a XML. I can get it as a Json too. but I need to make suitable response (add more parameters) for my client application. this is the xml response i got from endpoint.

```
<jsonObject>
<ddd>
    <__type>Title</__type>
    <AccountNo/>
    <AccountExists>1</AccountExists>
    <Name>user name</ConsumerName>
    <Address> user address</ConsumerAddress>
    <TotalDue>1000.38</TotalDue>
    <LastBillingCycleAmount/>
    <ID>150</ID>
</d>
```

and also this is the json output i can retrieve from endpoint

```
{
    "ddd": {
        "__type": "Title",
        "AccountNo": null,
        "AccountExists": 1,
        "Name": "user name",
        "Address": "address",
        "TotalDue": "1000.38",
        "LastBillingCycleAmount": null,
        "ID": 150
    }
}
```

I need transform response like this.

```
{
    "AccountNo": "response_data",
    "ConsumerName": "response_data",
    "ConsumerAddress": "response_data",
    "TotalDue": "response_data",
    "additional_para1": "my_data",      // parameter that i want to add manually
    "additional_para2": "my_data",      // parameter that i want to add manually
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a data mapper mediator [1] to map the input to the desired output. Then use a enrich mediator [2] to enrich the generated payload by adding your own values

[1]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.1.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/data-Mapper-Mediator/

[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Enrich+Mediator